# How do I answer this Computer Vision Theoretical question?

Tags: computer-vision

Suppose there is an image containing multiple objects of different types. The objective of the problem is to recognize objects using primary features of objects (colour, texture, shape). Explain your own idea what concepts will you apply, and how will you apply them, to differentiate/classify the objects in the image by extracting primary features (or combination of features) of objects. Also, justify how your idea can produce the best accuracy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to programming. Try asking on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: As @CrisLuengo mentioned SO is for programming related questions only. Hope my answer below gives you some starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a theoretical question, it can have many answers. The simplest approach is to use k-means or weighted k-means, using the features you have. If you have quite unique features then k-means would be able to classify decently accurately. You might still have to juggle around finding how you would input some of the more esoteric features to k-means though. Other more involved methods would use your own trained model using CNN for classification using the features you provide.

Since this is a theoretical question this is all the answer I can provide you with.